# Different Browser Window should have different menu option in electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I need the 2 browser Window one is main Window and other one is child window i want to set the child Window - menu that menu should not reflect on the main window  .

```
app.on('ready', function() {
  // Create new window
  // this assign the mainwindow variable as a browserwindow with 
  //      default parameter value which will take the entire page
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});
  childWindow = new BroserWindow({});
  // Load html in window
  // the below function will load the html into the window using the 
  //Command pathname
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'mainWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
  childWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'childWindow.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
  }));
  / /
  Quit app when closed
  mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
    app.quit();
  });
  // Build menu from template
  const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
  // Insert menu
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);
});
//here i need to set the menu option only to the child window 
//not the main window
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);` which is used to set as each window's top menu if no menu was explicitly defined.(Refer doc [doc](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu#menusetapplicationmenumenu)). You can use `MainWindow.setMenu(mainMenu)` to restrict menu only to mainWindow. Thereafter as your childWindow has no Menu defined, the default top menu will be appear there.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what your asking but from what I can tell you want to set a `menuBar` on the main window and a different `menuBar` on the child window.

You can do this with [`win.setMenu(menu)`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows) like this:

```
const mainWindowMenuBar  = Menu.buildFromTemplate(<Main window template>);
const childWindowMenuBar = Menu.buildFromTemplate(<Child window template>);

mainWindow.setMenu(mainWindowMenuBar);

childWindow.setMenu(childWindowMenuBar);
```

[Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows)